# URL format for SOAP Web service that returns a JSON response

Tags: ios, json, api, soap

I'm building an iOS app that relies on a web service. (using NSMutableURLRequest)

I've been trying to connect to the web service API which gives back a JSON response based on the parameters in the URL. but I'm getting invalid JSON parameters.

The guys that host the API have said my HTTP request should have the following format:

https://thewebserviceAPI?parameters={“api_key”:”YOUR_API_
KEY”,”query”:{“perpage”:50}}

I'm having no luck connecting at all. I was under the impression URL's with parameters had the format: 
https://thewebserviceAPI?firstParam=firstParamValue&secondParam=secondParamValue

But this format is not working for me.

Can some tell me what the correct format should be for this URL?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the double quotes are required. Working with this:

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://webServiceAPI?parameters={\"api_key\":\"YOUR_API_KEY\",\"query\":{\"perpage\":50}}";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                             [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```